# Navbar sumindo ao diminuir resolução

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou montando um projeto com `Bootstrap` porém estou enfrentando alguns problemas, um deles é o navbar sumindo quando diminui a resolução. O outro é que não consigo escrever um titulo bem no meio da tela.

**Navbar com problema.**

[image: navbar com problema]

**HTML**

```
    <header id="header">
     <div id="header-overlay"></div>
    </header>
    <div id="col-md-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top py-3 box-shadow mt-5">
     <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">LOGO</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Abrir Navegação">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#sobre">Sobre</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#solucoes">Soluções</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#contato">Contato</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">PT</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">EN</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ES</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ml-3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">Entrar</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*Header*/
#header {
 background: url("../img/header-bg.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 90%;
 z-index: -10;
 }

#header-overlay {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -5;
}
```

Outro problema que estou enfrentando é que preciso escrever um texto no meio desta tela porém quando escreve ele continua do lado do `navbar` e se tiro da tag `nav` ele escreve embaixo, preciso colocar sobre a imagem o texto e quando a imagem acabar começar o conteúdo do site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro seu BTN da Navbar está lá, ele só nã aparece pq vc não usou uma classe de cor na Navbar tipo `navbar-light`, ou `navbar-light`. No exemplo eu coloquei `navbar-dark` pro `btn` ficar branco.

Sobre o texto eu não entendi... se vc quer o texto depois da imagem é só colocar um `container>row>col>` seu texto, veja no exemplo para entender melhor. Para alinhar no centro o texto use a classe nativa do Bootstrap `text-center`

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
  /*Header*/
#header {
 background: url(https://placecage.com/300/200);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 90%;
 z-index: -10;
 }

#header-overlay {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -5;
}

#header h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 45%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<header id="header">
  <div id="header-overlay"></div>
  <h1 class="text-center text-light">Meu texto 123</h1>
</header>
<div id="col-md-12">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top py-3 box-shadow mt-5">
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">LOGO</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Abrir Navegação">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#sobre">Sobre</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#solucoes">Soluções</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#contato">Contato</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">PT</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">EN</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ES</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ml-3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">Entrar</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu preciso que o texto fique dentro da imagem, como uma apresentação, dai depois inicia o conteúdo.

Comment: E como pode ver no meu css eu deixei a imagem com 100vh, pois foi o unico jeito que consegui de exibir ela sem cortar, porém 100vh é muito grande, preciso que ela fique menor mas não corte.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti olha ai o código fiz um edite, o seu texto H1 tem que ficar dentro do header. e ai é só ajustar com um top nele. Sobre a imagem na verdade ela está com 90% da altura...

Comment: sobre a imagem foi viagem minha, já vi aqui que ta correto. Vou tentar colocar o texto agora.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti ele precisa do css tb, olha ai no código, deixei no final o CSS referente a esse h1 `#header h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 45%;
}` e no html fica dentro da div `<header id="header"> ... <h1>  </header>`

Comment: Corrigido, erro meu haha. muito obrigado cara

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti demoro jovem, qq dúvida estamos na área!

Comment: Já que perguntou, como posiciono um `a` para ele se adequar a qualquer resolução, pois do jeito que to fazendo `padding` na mão não ta rolando.

Comment: Ele vem depois dos textos do header, um botão embaixo deles, os textos já ta ok.

Comment: Tipo que depois do texto do H1 vc quer uma tag `<a>` pra poder fazer um btn etc é isso?

Comment: E tipo não tem como eu clicar no meu botão, pois pra fazer o overlay utilizei um `z-index` no `header` e no `overlay` para botar ele lá, a opção seria colocar o botão dentro do `nav` ?

Comment: Isso ai @hugocsl

Comment: Sera que não tinha como eu fazer todo esse efeito utilizando o bootstrap ? Um overlay na imagem do header com um navbar por cima e um texto no centro, tudo isso utilizando um tamanho fixo de imagem, que por exemplo eu não quero a imagem do tamanho total dela, mas eu não quero cortar ela, eu só preciso diminuir ela no css.

Comment: Não sei se me entendeu bem o que eu precisava

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti cara entendi sim, o z-index negativo não deixa o elemento clicável! A verdade é que esse header seu com bootstrap não está bem formatado não. Digo a estrutura no HTML, por isso que está precisando de fazer tanto "jeitinho" ai... Acho que vc deviria aproveitar que está no começo e parar uma meia horinha pra ver a documentação do Grid do Bootstrap. Vai te ajuda MUITO!!

Comment: Eu até acho que consigo resolver isso. Tirando o texto do Header. Mas pra deixar ele ali nessa posição novamente vamos ter que fazer outro "jeitinho". Jeitinho que seria muito melhor de fazer se estivesse com o Grid do BS4 direitinho. Acho que vc pode abrir outra pergunta, falar desse problema do Z-index e do link, e pedir ajuda com o Grid, falando que da forma que está vc está tendo problemas de alinhamento e o link fica inacessível etc... Ai eu ou outro membro pode te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Se quiser arrumar o texto na gambiarra mesmo vc pode colocar o H1 **do lado de fora** do Heade. E mude o CSS do H1 para isso: `h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}`

Comment: Acho melhor refazer então, porque se não vai ficar gambi em cima de gambi. Porém tu tem alguma ideia de como fazer a imagem no formato que preciso com o bootstrap ?

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti sim vc pode usar um container-fluid, ou um jombotron do Boostrap 4 e colocar nele um background-imagem e o texto dentro etc. Não tem muito segredo. Deve até dar para aproveitar sua navbar, o problema é a organização do html e o uso do grid...